# How add a row of 0 to a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have this dataframe in R

```
mat <-structure(list(a = c(2, 5, 90, 77, 56), b = c(45, 78, 98, 55, 
63), c = c(77, 85, 3, 22, 4), d = c(52, 68, 4, 25, 79), e = c(14, 
73, 91, 87, 94)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```

and I want add a row of "0" as first row of mat. The output that I need is

```
   a  b  c  d  e
1  0  0  0  0  0
2  2 45 77 52 14
3  5 78 85 68 73
4 90 98  3  4 91
5 77 55 22 25 87
6 56 63  4 79 94
```

How can I do? Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rbind`

```
mat <- rbind(0, mat)
```

-output

```
mat
   a  b  c  d  e
1  0  0  0  0  0
2  2 45 77 52 14
3  5 78 85 68 73
4 90 98  3  4 91
5 77 55 22 25 87
6 56 63  4 79 94
```

Comment: Is there a `dplyr` way through `dplyr::add_row(.before = 0)`?

Comment: @Julian you can use `add_row`, but it returns a default value of `NA` i.e. `add_row(mat, .before = 0)`

Comment: @Julian You could use that either changing value afterwards or `add_row(mat, !!! setNames(rep(0, ncol(mat)), names(mat)), .before = 0)`

Comment: Wow, yes that what I was looking for. Giving it the named vector is the key, I didn't know that that works through using `!!!` .  Thanks @akrun!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using `tidyverse`, where we iterate through each column to add a 0 to the first position, then bind back together as a dataframe.

```
library(tidyverse)

map_df(mat, ~ c(0, .x))
```

**Output**

```
      a     b     c     d     e
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0     0     0     0
2     2    45    77    52    14
3     5    78    85    68    73
4    90    98     3     4    91
5    77    55    22    25    87
6    56    63     4    79    94
```

Or another option would be to keep only the first row of the dataframe, then change all the values to 0, then use `bind_rows` to add to `mat`.

```
bind_rows(mutate(mat[1, ], across(everything(), ~ 0)), mat)
```